# Dark Eclipse themes don't work correctly

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, themes, eclipse-mars

I tried two different dark themes in Eclipse Mars, **Moonrise UI** and **Dark**. Most parts change color after applying one of those themes, but some don't, as you can see here:

[image: eclipse dark theme error]

I tried to restart and create a new workspace, but I still have these errors with both themes.

I am running Ubuntu 15.04.

Do you have any ideas?